# How do I add a Lead Source option

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to add options to the Source dropdown on the Leads screen. The field uses the CRMSourcesAttribute class to define the existing list. After simply creating a new attribute class to add my own items, I extend the CRLead.Source CacheAttached event to use my new attribute class instead. The result is that there is no change - the new dropdown items are not shown. After doing this, if I inspect the field and select the Drop Down Values button, I do actually see the new options in the Drop Down Values popup window. Any ideas on what could be preventing the new options from displaying in the dropdown itself?

Here's how I configure it in my LeadMaint graph extension:

```
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(CRMSourcesAttribute))]
    [CRMSourcesExt]  // list with old + new options
    protected virtual void _(Events.CacheAttached<CRLead.source> e) { }
```

(v20R2)

Comment: There's another step after overriding the drop down list. You need the tick them explicitly in the workflow of the opportunity screen of your project.

Comment: I had a suspicion that workflows was possibly affecting it.  The new items don't show up under the workflow for Opportunities, they show up for Leads where I implemented it.  However, I can't enable them - the checkbox doesn't check.  Do I need to implement it for Opportunity as well? And how are customization developers supposed to know that a workflow needs modified?  Is there a way to do this in code instead?

Comment: I did the same for Opportunity Source and the same thing occurs -- the workflow Source values popup window shows my new options, but I can't check the checkbox beside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use code and create a new attribute class with new options, then override the DAC field to use it instead. However, as far as I know, you still have to go through the steps of activating the new options in the workflow customizations UI for each of the fields you're overriding. But then you can refer to the new options in code without having to search the list's AllowedValues at runtime.

Comment: However, the same Source options for a Contact doesn't seem to work the same way. The workflow customization won’t let me create a workflow for this field without disabling automation steps, and I don't yet know the ramifications of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

With help from a colleague, I was able to get it working, and “without code” through screen workflow customization. I removed my code, then customized it with a new custom Workflow copied from the default. Not sure yet of the ramifications of this, like if we can access the new options in other real code or not, but I see how to create these options now. It has to also be done for both Lead and Opportunity in this scenario. It’s a bit tedious and ethereal (good word) though. I can see this easily causing problems and unexpected results for us we’ll want to watch out for.

**Update 5/28/21:** I added the options in the Workflow customizations for the field, then copied the default workflow to a new workflow, activated it, and activated the new options for each state/transition. I don't like it, but Acumatica tells me "that's just the way it is now". Note: you'll want to do this for other places referencing CRMSourcesAttribute as well, such as Opportunity.

Comment: How did you managed to add into the list in the custom workflow "without code" ?

Comment: @Rick, I updated my answer with more details.