# Not able to customize Lead screen Source dropdown

Tags: c#, acumatica, erp

Error: The entry form (ID: CR301000, title: Leads) cannot be automated. An item with the same key has already been added.

```
// Summary:
//     The source of the lead.
//
// Value:
//     The field can have one of the values listed in the PX.Objects.CR.CRMSourcesAttribute
//    class. The value of the field is automatically changed when the PX.Objects.CR.CRLead.ClassID
//     property is changed.
        
[CRMSources(BqlTable = typeof(CRLead))]        
[PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true)]        
[PXFormula(typeof(BqlOperand<Selector<classID, CRLeadClass.defaultSource>, IBqlString>.When<BqlChainableConditionBase<TypeArrayOf<IBqlBinary>.FilledWith<And<Compare<False, Equal<Use<IsImport>.AsBool>>>>>.And<Brackets<BqlChainableConditionBase<TypeArrayOf<IBqlBinary>.FilledWith<And<Compare<EntryStatus, Equal<EntryStatus.inserted>>>>>.Or<BqlOperand<Current<source>, IBqlString>.IsNull>>>>.Else<source>))]        
[PXMassMergableField]        
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Source")]
        
public override string Source { get; set; }
```

My DACExtension Code:

```
public class CRLeadExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.CRLead>
{
        #region
        [NewSources]
        [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
        [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(CRMSourcesAttribute))]
        public string Source { get; set; }
        #endregion
}
```

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67632384/how-do-i-add-a-lead-source-option). There are extra steps involving workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dropdown list for the Source field by replacing the current attribute [CRMSources(...)] list with a customized one as follow:

```
protected void _(Events.RowSelected<CRLead> e)
{
   string[] values = new[] { "S", "C", "R", "O", "W", "H", "L" };
   string[] labels = new[] {
               "My Organic Search",
               "My Campaign",
               "My Referral",
               "My Other Stuff",
               "Internet",
               "Phone Call",
               "Purchased List"};
            
   PXStringListAttribute.SetList<CRLead.source>(e.Cache, e.Row, values, labels);
}
```

You can see the outcome as:

[image]

**Previous answer comment**
Indeed, seems that doing a CacheAttached replacement like below does not work.

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]
[PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Source")]
[NewSources]
public void _(Events.CacheAttached<CRLead.source> e) { }
```

Remember, DAC extensions are only for additional fields.

Comment: Followed what you said but not working. this is the error I am getting "An item with the same key has already been added." In NewSources I have inherited CRMSourcesAttribute and added my new fields to it. I also tried using [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)] [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(CRMSourcesAttribute))]